# Invoking python script in Linux Terminal from java programmatically

Tags: java, python, linux, terminal, processbuilder

I am developing a Java application for inspecting patches (present if any or not) in the source files. The core logic for detecting the patch changes is present in a python script [titled 'patch.py'] and my Java application communicates with this Python Patch script for retrieving the operation's exit status.

The python script can be obtained from [here](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch)

In windows, it was working fine, but in Linux env. the script itself is not getting invoked from the Java application. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

I'm using 'ProcessBuilder' for invoking the python script and the source code is as follows :

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("Windows") != -1) {

            ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Cmd prompt will be launched, if platform is Windows.
            command.add("cmd");
            command.add("/c");
            command.add("python");

            command.add("lib/patch.py");
            command.add("-d");
            command.add(auxSrcFile);
            command.add(diffFileLoc);
            command.add("--revert");   // switch to revert the patch

            pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            //xterm will be launched, if platform is Linux.
            command.add("xterm");
            command.add("-e");
            command.add("python");
            command.add("lib/patch.py");
            command.add("-d");
            command.add(auxSrcFile);
            command.add(diffFileLoc);
            command.add("--revert");    // switch to revert the patch

            pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        }

        if (pb != null) {

            p = pb.start();                         
            if (p != null) {
                p.waitFor();
            }
        }   
        int exitStatus = p.exitValue();
        if(exitStatus == 1) {
            System.out.println("...OK");
            System.out.println(" ----Patch detected------");    
        } else {
            System.out.println("...ERROR");
            System.out.println(" ----Patch not found------");
        }
```

The python script is being invoked properly, if running the Java application in Windows whereas the same fails if I run the application in Linux environment.

Suggestions are welcomed !!

Note :  I'm able to run the 'patch.py' script standalone (in Linux terminal) but when I'm trying to invoke the same from my Java application, I'm unable to invoke it and always getting an exit value of '0'.

Comment: this feels like a path issue, are you sure you're managing paths correctly? you shouldn't have strings with slashes, as this is handled differently by different OSs

Comment: @TimP : Yes I believe that path should not be an issue, because when trying to run the same command (with "lib/patch.py") in standalone, I'm able to execute the script without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) solves the issue.

The following snippet works well

```
String[] cmd = {
                "python","lib/patch.py",
                "-d", auxSrcFile,
                diffFileLoc,
                "--revert"
        };
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        if (p != null) {
            p.waitFor();
        }
        p.destroy();
```